# how do I log dir from FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made a FTP script but I need logging of the transfer
specially a list of the files on the remote FTP (result of ls or dir)
And now I only get a log of the FTP commands, not the result

get.bat

```
ftp -v -n -i -s:D:\AX\get.ftp >>D:\AX\ftplog.txt
```

get.ftp

```
open ftp.xxxxxx.xx 
user xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
binary
cd /OUT
ASCII
ls >>D:\AX\ftplog.txt
lcd "\Import"
mget *.* s
mdelete *.*
bye
```

result:

```
open ftp.xxxxxx.xx 
user xxxxxx
binary
cd /OUT
ASCII
ls >>D:\AX\ftplog.txt
lcd "\Import"
mget *.* s
bye
```

and what i want to see is:

```
230 Login successful.
ftp> dir
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxrwxrwx    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Apr 25 10:10 IN
drwxrwxrwx    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Apr 24 15:39 OUT
226 Directory send OK.
ftp: 121 bytes received in 0,02Seconds 7,56Kbytes/sec.
```

how do i do that

Comment: that must be windows, not DOS, right?

Answer (score 2):

read `FTP -?` and notice the `-v` parameter that, according the documentation, means

**-v** *Suppresses display of remote server responses.*

so, remove the parameter from the command line

```
 ftp -n -i -s:D:\AX\get.ftp >>D:\AX\ftplog.txt
```